# Detecting Phone numbers in iOS App

Tags: ios

I am developing an iOS app, where I would need to access the phone number of the user logging in, query the DB to check if the phone number exists as an entry & finally display an alert to the user. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Read Apple response on this kinda app rejection..

**"For security reasons, iPhone OS restricts an application (including its preferences and data) to a unique location in the file system. This restriction is part of the security feature known as the application's "sandbox." The sandbox is a set of fine-grained controls limiting an application's access to files, preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on."**

so its not possible to read the user number by your application, best way to ask him to enter and validate at your server end!

[image]

[More detail about SandBox here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW4)

Comment: This is correct you have to ask the user to enter the number, You can't access from the device

Comment: Could you include the documentation this is from as well please. Not that I don't believe you it's just that I could write anything and say it's the Apple documentation so it's always good to include the actual documentation, at which point I will provide +1

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to detect phone numbers from an app.
However, there are solutions that allow phone number verification (after the user inputs his phone number) by placing missed calls.

I have used such a solution provided by an India-based company named [ZipDial](http://www.zipdial.com/corp/missed-call-marketing/).

Check the section titled "Mobile Number Verification" in the link above.